# TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int: when executing sqlAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I understand the error but I can't understand where it's coming from.

I have this query which returns a row from the DB:

```
test = DBSession.query(TTransformerTurnsRatio).filter(TTransformerTurnsRatio.ixSubReport == sub_rep_id).first()
```

This is what my table looks like:
[image]

How am I getting a TypeError exception here? I'm lost.

Comment: What does sub_rep_id reference? If it references an `int` you'll need to cast it into a string `str(sub_rep_id)` so the types in the equality statement match

Comment: sub_rep_id is the id of the subreport that I am getting from another table. When I'm debugging it says the id is of type 'int', which works in other queries. I've even tried to cast it to string but even that still gives me the same error

Comment: Found the problem. In sql server management studio I changed the value type of sTap to int from nvarchar. But in my models file I have sTap still as Unicode. So I believe that caused the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server management studio I changed the value type of sTap to int from nvarchar. But in my models file I have sTap still as Unicode.